# Variable declaration in C mingw

Tags: c, variable-declaration

I was reading C programming from a book that says all variables have to be declared in the beginning of the function. I tried following code but didn't issue any error. I am using mingw and codeblocks. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    printf("%d\n",i);

    int j=20;
    printf("%d\n",j);

    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to change any compiler setting or something to make it compatible with the standard given in the book?

I am using -std=c89 compiler option. See the compilation messages below:

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in HelloWorld (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "HelloWorld - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in HelloWorld (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -std=c89  -g     -c D:\MyCodeBlocksProjects\HelloWorld\main.c -o     obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe obj\Debug\main.o    
Output size is 68.53 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Adding `-std=c89` to your GCC command line will put the compiler in C89 mode.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I tried with -std=c89 option. Please see the compiler messages above. It still doesn't complain anything. Any more setting is required?

Comment: Since it doesn't *really* matter where the variables are declared, I'm not terribly surprised to find out that this warning will only be generated if you're using [`-pedantic`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), as [Yu Hao mentioned below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19750011/119527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all variables have to be declared in the beginning of the function.

To be precise, they have to be declared in the beginning of a **block**. And this is only true in C89. C99 has removed this limit. So you can change your compiler to strict C89 mode. For example, for GCC, it's `-std=c89` option. To obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify the option `-pedantic`.

To demonstrate what I mean by *in the beginning of a block*, this is legal C89 syntax:

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 1;
    x = x + 1;
    {
        int y = 42;  /**OK: declaration in the beginning of a block*/
    }
}
```